# django - TypeError: coercing to Unicode

Tags: python, django

I'm getting **TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, int found**

This is my models.py:

```
class FollowingModel(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    person = models.IntegerField(max_length=20, blank=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
            return self.person
```

When I retrieve the values from the **FollowingModel** in my views like this

```
g = FollowingModel.objects.all()
g[0] -----> I'm getting that error
```

I tried changing the `def __unicode__(self):` as

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return str(self.person)
```

But no use, still I'm getting the same error. Could anyone guide me?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

```
>>>g = FollowingModel.objects.all()
>>>g

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 72, in __repr__
return repr(data)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 370, in __repr__
u = unicode(self)
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, int found
```

Comment: Could you include a traceback, so we can diagnose where the error is coming from *exactly*?

Comment: @MartijnPieters If you need my views.py I can give, but I think there is no necessity for that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [`__unicode__` method should return just that, unicode](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__unicode__):

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return unicode(self.person)
```

Comment: @mk: `str` is not the same as `unicode`; the former is encoded data (ascii, utf-8, whatever), the latter is full Unicode text. The contract of the `__unicode__` method is that it'll *always* return `unicode`. Also see http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: I'm in no hurry :-) Lets give others a chance to answer too.